Fence repair method?
I inherited this fence that needs repair in one small section. It’s 4’ high, and the chain links are smaller than the standard fence, and it’s green rather than silver. Do you think this is something I can tackle, or better off getting a company to come in? 

Is any part of the damaged section salvageable?  And a lot depends on how tight the fence is stretched.

It looks like the previous owner cut away the section, like if a small tree or something grew through it, so I can’t simply stretch it back together to close the hole. I think I’d need to replace at least that one section of mesh. The whole fence is only about 50 feet long so if I can’t match the specific type of chain link then I guess the better option would be to replace all of it

How much do you really care about it being an exact match?

Also, how much do you care about aesthetics?

Doesn’t need to be totally exact, just not stick out like a sore thumb

Place a decoration there, e.g., two panels with large pictures of butterflies, sandwiching the gap, or giant sun flowers, or weave ribbons in a pattern (https://sun9-70.userapi.com/impg/GPMVeCjVVp0A2vaI04wPbx-S_pPcpR_gOkLP1w/0W2D8bsID1o.jpg?size=604x340&quality=95&sign=d200c166cc196b565ab7870b91b6073e&c_uniq_tag=Gt9nayczKuePPMWnpCZY8yYNYaSrLw8wgTQ2-xQ4Wdw&type=album)
